# Parameter evaluation and undefined behavior

Tags: c++, boost, undefined-behavior

Given this example (which is a simplication of an example in the documentation for [boost::multi_index_container](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/basics.html#ord_updating) about update rollbacks):

```
#include <iostream>

struct change
{
        int val_;
        change(int const &val) : val_(val)
        {
        }

        void operator() (int &v) const
        {
                v = val_;
        }
};

void do_it(int &v, change const &c1, change const &c2)
{
        c1(v);
        c2(v);
}

main()
{
        int i = 17;
        int orig = i;
        do_it(i, change(11), change(orig));
        std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl;
}
```

Is the explicit copy of `i` (into `orig`) needed here?  Or could this be more simply written as:

```
        int i = 17;
        do_it(i, change(11), change(i));
```

In that case, is the value of `i` after the call to `do_it` still guaranteed to be `17`?  Both `change` parameters would need to be constructed before the body of the function is executed.

Does the language guarantee that all of the parameters be constructed before the function begins?  (If there is no guarantee, then the compiler could delay the construction of `c2` until after `c1`'s `operator()` has run and thus the final value would be `11`)

Comment: They probably did this for clarity.  If a bug occured anywhere near that routine, I would feel compelled to verify that the behavior is indeed well defined by digging into `change`.  But with a new variable, there is no risk of `i` being in an invalid state upon entering `do_it`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the parameters to a function call are evaluated before the function is called. The order in which the parameters are evaluated is unspecified.

In your case `i` would still be 17.